# Serializing a very large list

Tags: java, serialization

I'm gettint a large amount of data from a database query and I'm making objects of them. I finally have a list of these objects (about 1M of them) and I want to serialize that to disk for later use. Problem is that it barely fits in memory and won't fit in the future, so I need some system to serialize say the first 100k, the next 100k etc; and also to read the data back in in 100k increments.

I could make some obvious code that checks if the list gets too big and then wirites it to file 'list1', then 'list2' etc but maybe there's a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go through the list, create an object, and then feed it immediately to an [ObjectOutputStream](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) which writes them to the file.

Comment: But does the OOS append to the file? And is there an equivalent way of reading the objects one by one back from the file?

Comment: Good answer.  FYI, I did something similar recently, and noticed big performance gains by wrapping my FileOutputStream in a BufferedOutputStream.  In turn, you can throw a GZIP OutputStream in there too, and save some disk space:

new ObjectOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream ( new FileOutputStream(myFile) ) ) );

Comment: The `ObjectOutputStream` will keep a reference to the objects you have written to it...

Comment: @Tom: you can call reset() on the stream and it will drop all references I believe. I'm not sure if writing all objects with writeUnshared, will any object references be kept at all.

Comment: @Tom: thanks, I'll have a good look at that. All objects are independent so it shouldn't keep references.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the objects one by one from the DB
2. Don't put them into a list but write them into the file as you get them from the DB

Never keep more than a single object in RAM. When you read the object, terminate the reading loop when `readObject()` returns `null` (= End of file)

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you checked, it's really necessary to save the data to disk. It couldn't stay in the database, could it?

---

To handle data that is too big, you need to make it smaller :-)

One idea is to **get the data by chunks**:

- start with the request, so you *don't build this huge list* (because that will become a point of failure sooner or later)
- serialize your smaller list of objects
- then loop

Answer (score 1):

Think about setting the fetch size for the JDBC driver also, for example the JDBC driver for mysql defaults to fetching the whole resultset.

read here for more information: [fetch size](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B25221_04/web.1013/b13593/optimiz011.htm#BEEBHBBG)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are retreiving a large dataset from db and convert them into list of objects and serialize them in a single shot.

Dont do that.. finally it may lead to application crash.

Instead you have to

- minimize the amount of data retrieved from database. (let say
  1000 records instead 1 M)
- convert them into business object
- And serialize them.
- And perform the same procedure until the last record

this way you can avoid the performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectOutputStream will work but it has more overhead. I think `DataOutputStream/DataInputStream` is a better choice.

Just read/write one by one and let stream worry about buffering. For example, you can do something like this,

```
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfile"));
    for (...)
        os.writeInt(num);
```

One Gotcha with both object and data stream is that write(int) only writes one byte. Please use writeInt(int).